# Spring JDBC one to one relationship

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring JDBC for an application that I am working on and I am facing an issue. In my domain layer I have fields; primitive types and object associations. If a Person belongs to a Municipality I have:

```
public class Person {

    private Municipality municipality;

    // More code
}

public class Municipality {
    // More code
}
```

In the database you model this with primary + foreign keys. The person table in this case have a foreign key to the primary key of the municipality table. I have created a repository for the Person and Municipality. Now I want to retrieve a Person, but I also want to connect the Municipality to it at the same time.

The first thing I do is to find the person using the Person repository. Then I want to find the Municipality that belongs the Person. However at the moment I do not have the foreign keys modeled in my domain objects. That means, I have no `private int municipality_id` field in the Person class. This will cause the domain objects to be coupled with databases (at least now about it).

Issuing another query just to find the municipality_id feels uncorrect. How can I solve this problem? However I need the municipality_id to find the municipality.

Comment: Add the municipalityId in the model, or use an ORM (JPA, Hibernate, etc.). Note: the model represents data coming from the database. What's the problem of having a field for the foreign key?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the domain layer "knows" about that I use database for persistence? I mean, why would you otherwise have a foreign key in the model? Or is it okey?

Comment: @LuckyLuke All the domain layer knows is that you can identify entities of other types with a unique number that lets you fetch them later from *some* persistent store. Unfortunately I'm not sure at all how you would make domain classes unaware of being persistable altogether.

Comment: Yeah, that is true. Hmm, maybe it is not that bad as I first thougth.

Comment: @LuckyLuke: Why would you be bothered by a foreign key, but not by a primary key? The model does represent what is stored in the database. It will have to be refactored every time the schema changes. And you'll have much bigger problems in the almost impossible case where you wouldn't use a relational database to store your data anymore. SOmetimes, the natural, pragmatic way is the better one.

Comment: @LuckyLuke Basically, my thinking is that the domain classes are allowed to handle the concern of *being persistable*. This means things like relying on the DAO layer to assemble the object graph. Making provisions for said DAO layer to be able to disassemble the object graph into ID-based links doesn't seem too out-of-place. Now, you *could* do something insane as have the DAO layer store "hidden" attributes externally to the domain classes, in a bunch of hashmaps or using bytecode enhancement, just to keep them out of your entity classes, but that sounds like overengineering horribly.

Comment: @LuckyLuke Now at some point you might transition to a document database, but all that would mean is that some of the foreign key fields would become unnecessary. This is fine as long as your domain code doesn't really access those fields and merely provides them for the DAOs. There's a purely hypothetical chance of using a database that needs something *more* than unique foreign keys to connect entities, but that's vanishingly unlikely. (Seeing as foreign keys were sufficient for this purpose for decades.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible options for you.

1. Include the municipality id on the person object. It sounds like you have a problem with this approach. This doesn't bother me. I would simply bring back the id along the other person data in the query.
2. Issue a second query to get the municipality and then populate the municipality on the person object. I don't see any issue with this approach either.
3. Join the two tables together and bring back the data for both objects. In your mapper you would create a municipality object and set that into the person object.